# Query seems to return no rows, but it does in Access

Tags: asp.net, sql

I use a querystring parameter to return a value that is then used in the code below:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PeoplePhotos] WHERE ID = @ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />                    
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <table class="picPageStyle">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picDesc") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The query would easily return a row when I substitute a value for "@ID" in Access and it seems (but it seems that I'm wrong) that it is returning the value because the address of the page that uses this code shows the right ID, i.e. "picpage.aspx?ID=4" What am I missing? Is it something with the querystring parameter?

Comment: Change Name="ID" to Name="@ID"

Comment: @RameshRajendran I tried putting the @ symbol in a couple of different locations to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be place Table into a FormView:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <table class="picPageStyle">
         <tr>
           <td>
              <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picDesc") %>' />
            </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the proper solution .

But you can try this way .

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PeoplePhotos] WHERE ID =" + <%= Request.QueryString["ID"] %>>
```

Don't need `asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />`

**Update** :

*Copy and past this code , then check*

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PeoplePhotos] WHERE ID =" + <%= Request.QueryString["ID"] %>>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" />                    
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
        <table class="picPageStyle">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picDesc") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to stop telling me that I need the proper quotation marks...

Comment: eh? so the proper syntax is SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PeoplePhotos] WHERE ID =" + <%= Request.QueryString[`"~/picpage.aspx?ID="4`] %> +">"

????

Comment: Oh, I think you are misunderstanding why I included the "picPage.aspx?ID=4" thing to begin with. That's the address in my address bar in my internet browser when I click on the link the previous page. If I included the whole thing it would be "http://localhost:49815/TravelJoansBlog/picPage.aspx?ID=1"

Comment: It's okay ! See my updated code , you can just copy then past that answer, if you have any issue,then tell me .

Comment: I pasted your code in and it gives me a "server tag not well formed" error and won't compile.

Comment: It changes the color of the text to look like "ID" is another property of the AccessDataSource control.

Comment: When I changed the code to this:

SelectCommand='SELECT * FROM [PeoplePhotos] WHERE ID = "<%# Request.QueryString["ID"] %>'>

It stopped giving me the errors, but still returned nothing. Kinda back to the drawing board thing.

Comment: You don't need # , should be want to = symbol . please look my updated code .

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and got the "Server tag not well formed" if I change the outermost "" to '', it gets rid of the error but still doesn't produce what I expect it to.