# None of my queries involving QueryString seem to work?

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I haven't been able to get any of my queries to work. They work when I use them in Access. For some reason, I just can't get them to work for my website. Am I missing some code behind or something? Is there any code behind I should have when I'm using a QueryString Parameter? Here are my previous posts about my previous queries:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370174/query-seems-to-return-no-rows-but-it-does-in-access/18370736?noredirect=1#comment26975031_18370736) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305740/my-query-works-in-access-but-not-in-visual-studio/18307681?noredirect=1#18307681)

Here is my current query and the associated ASP code:

StreetPhoto.aspx

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [StreetPhotos]">
</asp:AccessDataSource>

<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server"
    BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="30" 
    CellSpacing="2" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2"
    GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <ItemStyle BackColor="White" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "StreetPic.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID") %>'>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="Street Photo" 
        BorderWidth="1px" 
        Width="220px" 
        Height="180" 
        ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" +  Eval("picPath") %>' />
      </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:DataList>
```

And here is the StreetPic.aspx page that is linked to the above code:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [StreetPhotos] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<table class="streetTableStyle">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="Street Picture" BorderWidth="1px" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picCaption") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you able to navigate to the `StreetPic.aspx`?

Comment: @Nilesh Yes I am. It just acts like it returns no records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must placed table into a formView that bind to AccessDataSource

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <table class="streetTableStyle">
       <tr>
       <td>
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" AlternateText="Street Picture" BorderWidth="1px" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("picPath") %>' />
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>
        <asp:Label ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("picCaption") %>' />
       </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Comment: Thanks Samiey! I will give it a try in a bit.